# Download a list of files and use domain name as filename

Tags: download, wget, curl

I got a bunch of files to download which works great with

```
wget -i list_of_urls
```

but my problem is, that wget uses the filename of the downloaded file. Is there a way (or a different tool) which is able to use the whole url als filename, f.e.

```
http://www.example.com/file1.html
http://www.example.com/file2.html
```

Lead to the files:

```
http___www_example_com_file_1.html
http___www_example_com_file_2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some simple bash scripting.  For example, if you have a file "foo" with the URLs:

```
http://www.google.com/index.html
http://www.cnn.com/index.html
```

You can run:

```
for i in `cat foo`; do wget $i -O `echo $i | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g' | sed 's/_html$/.html/'`; done
```

which produces

```
http___www_cnn_com_index.html
http___www_google_com_index.html
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: @Karimi Feel free to upvote the question and answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the ["-x" option documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options).  For example, given a file "foo" with contents:

```
http://www.google.com/index.html
http://www.cnn.com/index.html
```

If you run

```
wget -x -i foo
```

then you will get these files:

```
www.google.com/index.html
www.cnn.com/index.html
```

Comment: That's nice but I really need a single file with the full name